# How can I convert a session variable to a string array?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to store an array in a session variable then use it latter like this:

```
        Session["sessionVariable"] = searchString;
```

Now here I’m trying to store the session variable into a string variable.

```
        String[] sv = Session["sessionVariable"];
```

When I do I get his error.

Cannot explicitly convert type ‘Object’ to ‘String[]’, An explicit conversion exists, (are you mission a cast?)

I’ve tried various conversions but can’t find the correct one.  Can you please help me to find the correct conversion?  Thanks.

Comment: searchString is already a string array being passed into the method like this:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

Set:

```
Session["test"] = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
```

Get:

```
string[] array = Session["test"] as string[];
```